# Regular Expression for all string over {a,b} without abb

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that excludes the string 'abb' ONLY. All other combinations are possible.

So far I have:
b*+a*(a*aba*)*+a*(a*ba)*a+a*(ba)*(a+ab)*a+a*(ab)*(a+ab)*.

Which is a bit long.

Comment: Note that the markup language here reads text enclosed in asterisks as italic.  That is `*text*` is rendered as *text*.  You may want to edit your post, perhaps using some MathJax, to make it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a DFA accepting the strings over $\Sigma=\{A,B\}$ not having $ABB$ as a substring:

`____
             /     A _______A____ 
             \     //            \
Start--A-> [Prefix A] --B-> [Prefix AB] --B-> Discard
    \          ^
     B         A    ________
      \        |   /        \
       --> [Prefix B*] --B->/`

After reading the first character we either stay in the bottom line forever, or we reach the states in the first line, accepting cycles like $A^+$ and $(BA)^+$, for finishing (at $\text{[Prefix A]}$) with an $A$ or (at $\text{[Prefix AB]}$) with a $B$. It follows that

$$B^*(A\{\varepsilon,B\})^*$$
(thanks to [Fabio Somenzi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/123852/fabio-somenzi) for spotting an inaccuracy in the previous version of this answer) is a more compact representation of the strings accepted by the DFA above.

---

The transition matrix of the DFA can be represented as
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
having eigenvalues $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2},1$. $L_n$, the number of strings with length $n$ fulfilling the wanted constraint, is so $\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 \varphi^n+\lambda_n \overline{\varphi}^n$ with $\varphi$ being the golden ratio. Since $L_1=2, L_2=4, L_3=7$ we simply have $L_n = \color{red}{F_{n+3}-1}$ with $F_n$ being the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: fixed the intro, too.